# Как реализовать функцию snprintf?

Tags: c, linux

Уже реализованы функции `sprintf`, `vprintf`

Читал, что `snprintf` идентична функции `sprintf` за исключением того, что в массиве будет сохранено заданное количество символов.

Пользоваться стандартными библиотеками не могу, т.к. код исполняется до загрузки операционной системы.

Не могу сообразить, подскажите пожалуйста идеи.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не ясно, какие у вас проблемы с использованием кода написанной вами функции sptintf в реализации функции snprintf.

Comment: Эм.. Ты случайно не ту проблему в ядре пытаешься исправить, про которую когда-то писали?

Comment: А где код посмотреть можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет. К ядру я никакого отношения не имею... Код, к сожалению, показать тоже не могу

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вот идея второго комментатора показалась здравой. Осталось реализовать. Хотел просто в реализации snprintf выставить функцию sprintf, но, похоже, прийдется использовать ее код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать так же как и sprintf, но добавить счетчик записанных байт и проверку, влезут ли новые данные. Если не влезут, записывать только часть.

Comment: Я вот представил примерную реализацию - там явно важный момент запись чисел. Ну и на форматирование обратить внимание имеет смысл.

Comment: Спасибо! Под вечер уже голова вообще не варит... Попробую так и сделать. @Qwertiy о каком форматировании идет речь?

Comment: @MaximGusev, `%200s` и всё т таком духе.

Answer (score 1):

`snprintf` - это тот же самый `sprintf`, но не "страдающий" переполнением буфера.
Второй аргумент `snprintf` - это размер выходного буфера, т.е. **максимальный** размер строки, которая может получиться на выходе.
По-хорошему, надо делать наоборот - сделать реализацию `snprintf`, а `sprintf` получится сам - можно просто не контролировать длину буфера.

Comment: К сожалению, все получилось как раз наоборот...

Comment: @MaximGusev, обычно сначала реализуют `vsnprintf()`, а все остальное ее вызывает. / А Вы просто тренируетесь или готовые реализации чем-то не устраивают?

Comment: @avp подключаю графическую оболочку. Она использует некоторые функции, которых у меня нет, вот и приходится реализовывать